# Database error while queueing user profiles

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, user-profile

I am attempting to enumerate the user profiles in my SharePoint environment using the following script:

```
$sc = [microsoft.sharepoint.spservicecontext]::getcontext((get-spsite $url))
$upm = new-object microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager($sc)
$upm.getenumerator()
```

but upon executing that, i get the following error:

```
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Database error while queueing user profiles..
```

some other useful info:

```
$upm.count = 0
$sc.sitesubscriptionid = all zeroes
```

the user profile enumerator should be returning hundreds of user profiles.
yes, i am an administrator of the User Profile service, and yes, I have site collection admin on the site collection used to get the service context.

This error message showed up nowhere else on the internet, so I figured it was worth asking here, even if it's not all that important for my solution that I solve it.

Comment: I have this same issue. It seems to be intermittent since the code runs inside a daily job and it only fails sometimes.